# Can I link a pull request to a work item in a different VSTS account?

Tags: azure-devops

My company has a VSTS account, which we manage our work items through. My team would like to create our own VSTS account to manage our own repos, build pools, etc, but we'd still like to associate our pull requests with work items in that other VSTS account. Is there any way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VSTS pull request linked work items only for the same VSTS account. That’s because we can add other accounts in the account, so the account stand for all the connections of a whole project.

For your situation, you need to [add a team](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams) in your company account instead of creating a new account. In the new added team, you can still use your company account other teams' work items.