# How can I associate a PR with a work item in a different subscription

Tags: azure-devops

My distributed team works in two different subscriptions, lets call them
sub1.visualstudio.com and sub2.visualstudio.com.  It's not practical to add them as a team in our company account, as suggested here: [Can I link a pull request to a work item in a different VSTS account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146033/can-i-link-a-pull-request-to-a-work-item-in-a-different-vsts-account)

Our repo is in sub1.visualstudio.com, but the other team keeps its work items in sub2.visualstudio.com

How can I associate a work item in sub2.visualstudio.com with my PR's in sub1.visualstudio.com?

Alternatively, Is there any way to mirror work items between two subscriptions with some kind of bot connector or something?

Comment: how about to [move the repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) in sub1 to sub2 and let the team work on sub2?

Answer (score 0):

afaik, it is not possible to connect PR from one subscription to a WI in another. The only way to link them would be by adding an external hyperlink.

The are a few options to replicate your workitems. For example, one would be to use a Logic App in Azure which will be triggered automatically on update/create etc... The other way would be to use, for example [azure-devops-migration-tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools) and create a schedule.